# How to create a excel VBA loop to print text("x") in cell A5,B4,C3,D2,E1

Tags: excel, vba, loops

The image shows what I am trying to print,not sure how it can be achieved with a loop.
[image]

This is what I've been trying to solve the problem, what am I doing wrong?

```
Sub x()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim y As Long
    For i = 1 To 5
        For y = 5 To 1 Step -1
            Cells(y, i).Value = "x"
        Next y
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You should break this problem up into smaller pieces: (1) how do I print "x" into a hard-coded cell. (2) how do I advance to the next column/decrement current row, and (3) what is the general syntax of a loop in vba? Then put all of those pieces together. If you have figured out ANY of those pieces so far, you should [Edit] your question, and include the steps you already know how to do, even if they don't fully work yet.

Comment: Since you know that this is what you'd like to print, why would you use a loop?

Comment: Using the below I can print text "x" in cells(1,1) to (5,5)
For i = 1 To 5
    Cells(i,i).Value = "x"
Next i
This looks Simple but for the one that I am trying to do I tried the below and not sure how to get it done.
For i = 1 To 5
    For y = 5 to 1 Step -1
        Cells(i,y).Value = "x"
    Next y
Next i
For every counter in the outer loop the inner loop runs all, I tried Exit For in the inner loop, it didn't help to solve the problem. Thank you @Lynn Crumbling for your advise.. I tried this before asking here..

Comment: @Danny I have scenarios in a project where solving this problem will help. Hypothetically x for now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you can do this with a loop:

```
Sub x()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 5
        Cells(6 - i, i).Value = "x"
    Next i
End Sub
```